# SwipeListView "phantom" clicked state after a row dismiss - how to clear clicked state?

Tags: android, android-widget

**ABOUT**
I am using the SwipeListView library: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

**PROBLEM**
I've discovered that dismissing a row, and calling `.recycle(cell, position);` in the adapter causes the next row to be in a clicked state.

This causes the next row to become highlighted because the layout's background uses a selector.

When I remove the `state_pressed="true"` from the selector, this problem goes away but of course the row no longer highlights when the user clicks the row - which is not good.

**QUESTION**
How is it possible to reset a layout's clicked state ?
My plan is to reset the clicked state in the listview's adapter during `getView()`